# What's the result of $(A^{-1}BC^{T})^{T}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

I know it's a very simple one but still worth it, say we have 3 real matrices 3x3, $A,B,C$, what is $(A^{-1}BC^T)^T$?

Is it $(A^{-1})^T B^T C$? Or since it is transpose we have to change the order of the product is it $CB^T (A^{-1})^T$, I'm quite confused

Comment: Yes, the transpose of AB is B^T A^T, etc. Your last expression is correct. (And note that (A^-1)^T  =  (A^T)^-1.)  But these things are also extremely easy to look up on the Internet.

Comment: Transpose, like inverse, follows the "socks-shoes" rule - if you put socks on then shoes, you undo by taking off the shoes first then socks. So it is in the reverse order.